# Buffered communication in hard real time communication on multicore processor - good idea ?

Tags: operating-system, scheduled-tasks, real-time, communication, multicore

The situation is: Scheduled tasks (with runnables) on multicore processors have to communicate with each other through shared global variables on a real-time system. Multiple runnables update same global value at the same time. This value will be stored in buffer. To ensure the correct value available for use, I am thinking to use read-modify-write class for buffer to avoid mutual exclusion, locks etc.

I want to know your opinions and comments about it e.g will the use of buffer with read-modify-write technique in real-time communication systems, work ? or is there any better technique to be used in such scenario ?

Please comment.

Comment: OK, can you give just ONE thread access to the buffer, and queue requests to it?  That is often a cleaner design, easier to debug and less prone to deadlocks than multiple complex-locks.

Comment: This is what I also have been thinking on. Lets say it "wait-free locking with helping" used with a ring buffer, where one thread can access the buffer at a time with "read-modify-write" using atomic operations and update threads afterwards using multiple read pointer. With this it can avoid race-conditions and mutexes etc ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to avoid locks/mutexes for your read-modify-write class. The problem is that with two threads and no locks, it turns into a read-read-modify-modify-write-write class.